# Copying elements of an array using for loop vs struct pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

If I have two arrays of the same size, let's say,

```
int pa1[100];
int pa2[100];
```

I know that if, at some point in the code, I want to copy the contents of pa2 in pa1,

```
pa1 = pa2;
```

is not the correct way to do it. Instead I could use perhaps a loop. However I was thinking that if I had two struct pointers (ps1, ps2) it is valid to write:

```
*ps1 = *ps2;
```

If that structure contained a 100 int array, and I made ps1 and ps2 point to pa1 and pa2 respectively, what is the difference between the previous instruction and a loop that copies every single element in the arrays?

```
for (int i = 0; i<100; i++) pa1[i] = pa2[i];
```

Does it have any performance difference? Why?

My first guess is that using the pointers is better than using a loop, but I am not sure. I tried to make a web search but had no success, maybe because I could not find the exact words that describe what I want to know.

Comment: A modern compiler will probably see both your options as the same operation, and should emit same or similar code.  Best to code for readability in this instance.  Second best option is to explicitly call `memcpy()`, which the compiler may also optimise away.

Answer (score 1):

Usually compilers uses standard C function `memcpy` in such cases. It is much faster then using a manually written loop.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it works, as the program below demonstrate.

No you can't be really sure of the code the compiler will choose to do internally. But it is likely that the compiler will emit a very efficient code like calling memcopy (but no include necessary) or using optimized assembly.

But it can't be guaranteed. You will have to test or analyse generated assembly output.

On the readability part I believe copying structure is at least as easy to read than an explicit loop or call to memcopy. And it could be even better if the two arrays are acompanied by other variables related to the arrays that could also go to the structures.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    struct {
        int t[10];
    } s1, s2;

    int i = 0;
    for(i=0; i < 10 ; ++i){
        s1.t[i] = i;
        s2.t[i] = -1;
    }

    printf("s1 [%d %d ... %d %d] s2 [%d %d ... %d %d]\n",
        s1.t[0], s1.t[1], s1.t[8], s1.t[9], 
        s2.t[0], s2.t[1], s2.t[8], s2.t[9]);

    s2 = s1;

    printf("s1 [%d %d ... %d %d] s2 [%d %d ... %d %d]\n", 
        s1.t[0], s1.t[1], s1.t[8], s1.t[9], 
        s2.t[0], s2.t[1], s2.t[8], s2.t[9]);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean this?

```
int pa1[100], pa2[100];
int *ps1 = pa1, *ps2 = pa2;

// Initialize the arrays

*ps1 = *ps2;
```

If it is, then all the last line is doing is:

```
pa1[0] = pa2[0];
```

nothing else.
If you need to copy all elements of an array to the other, you **will** need to iterate through them.

EDIT: On a second read, now I think you meant this:

```
struct a{
    int v[100];
};

int pa1[100], pa2[100];
a *ps1, *ps2;

// Initialize the arrays

ps1 = (a*)pa1;
ps2 = (a*)pa2;

*ps1 = *ps2;
```

Pretty clever, although you won't find a definite answer for your question. That's implementation-specific, altough many implementations seem to use memcpy or something like it, witch may be barely a little faster than iterating the array. On a second note, your compiler will easily optimize a copy between two arrays using iteration, so the difference is probably negligible, and not worth the extra effort in writing the struct and the pointers in the first place.

So, the real question here is: why do you need such an optimization?

Comment: Ah, I get it. Maybe something on the lines of the edit I just made?

Comment: @cassiorenan It might take too long to explain what I am specificately doing with those structs and arrays. I could just say that I am using a micro-controller with limited resources with a severe real time performance requirments application. Hence, I need to optimize every single line of code as much as I can to guarantee the best real time performance. That idea occured to me while trying to avoid loops. I have been thinking, and perhaps it also depends on how the MCU manages memory, at its hardware architecture level, am I wrong?

Comment: @esal26 are you using a modern compiler? By mangling your code you would make it more difficult for a compiler such as gcc to optimize. (However if you are stuck with a buggy 20-year-old setup then you may have no option)

Comment: @MattMcNabb I am using avr-gcc